# Proof that $P(A \cup B^c)=P(A)-P(A \cup B)+1$

Tags: probability

I want to show that $P(A \cup B^c)=P(A)-P(A \cup B)+1$, so I try to use the identity

$$A \cup B=A \cup (B \cap A^c)$$

But it seems that when I do it for the equality on the left, the sets do not end up being disjoint and therefore I cannot separate the union as a sum.

Maybe as $A \subseteq A \cup B$ then $P(A - (A \cup B))=P(A \cup B)- P(A)$. But I don't quite see how to connect these ideas, any suggestions?

Comment: $1 - P(A \cup B^c) = P(A^c \cap B) = P(A \cup B) - P(A)$

Comment: @VezenBU Could you please explain a little bit the last step?

Comment: $A \cup B = A \cup (A^c \cap B)$ with $A \cap (A^c \cap B) = \emptyset$, i.e., $(A \cup B) \setminus A = A^c \cap B$.

Comment: Maybe drawing a Venn diagram may help

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$P(B) + P(B^c) = 1 \\
P(A \cap B) + P( A \cap B^c ) = P(A)
$$
And of course the inclusion exclusion principle are the three identities you need here. Let me know if you have extra questions. I can post a full proof in the morning if you would like.